# Email creation script for Wamp

Tags: php, html, smtp, wamp

I would like to make it available for clients to create emails through a web based interface without me having to go to mercury mail program and add a new user every time. i just need a source or script that will allow my clients to create emails on my wampserver email system.

I'm using MercuryMail as my mail host and i'm currently public with my server but need an email creation script that i can put into a web page. Preferably PHP.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open the “php.ini“. You should know where it is located because it depends upon the particular server you’re running.

2) Search for the attribute called “SMTP” in the php.ini file.Generally you can find the line “SMTP=localhost“. change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. And, there is another attribute called “smtp_port” which should be set to 25.I’ve set the following values in my php.ini file.

```
SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np
smtp_port = 25
```

3) Restart the apache server so that PHP modules and attributes will be reloaded.

4) Now try to send the mail using the mail() function ,

```
mail(“you@yourdomain.com”,”test subject”,”test body”);
```

you might get the warning like this,

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: “sendmail_from” not set in php.ini or custom “From:” header missing in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\testmail.php on line 1

5) Now specify the following headers and try to send the mail again,

```
$headers = ‘MIME-Version: 1.0′ . “\r\n”;
$headers .= ‘Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1′ . “\r\n”;
$headers .= ‘From: sender@sender.com’ . “\r\n”;
mail(“you@yourdomain.com”,”test subject”,”test body”,$headers);
```

Well that’s all, the mail is sent to “you@yourdomain.com” from the localhost.

Note : Some smtp server verifies the email address of the sender so the email address which is in the place of “sender@sender.com” should be a valid and existing email address otherwise mail might not be sent to the “you@yourdomain.com”.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He wants to create email accounts automatically for clients.

Comment: @MarcB 
yeah mark that's exactly what i want to do. i want to allow clients to create there own email account on my server. i already can send mail to and from my server. i just need a script or something that is php based to allow clients to create emails on my server.